# Better understanding of Singleton class in C++

Tags: c++, reference, singleton

I've written a very simple program implementing a generic Singleton class as follow:

```
namespace core
{
    template <typename T>
    class Singleton
    {
        protected:
            Singleton(void);
            Singleton(Singleton const &other);
            virtual ~Singleton(void);
        public:
            Singleton &operator=(Singleton const &other);
            static T *GetSingletonPtr(void);
            static T &GetSingleton(void);
            static void DestroySingleton(void);
        private:
            static T *m_pInstance;
            static T m_Instance;
    };

    //Globals initialization

    template <typename T>
    T *Singleton<T>::m_pInstance = NULL;

    template <typename T>
    T Singleton<T>::m_Instance = T();

    //Initialization

    template <typename T>
    Singleton<T>::Singleton(void)
    {

    }

    template <typename T>
    Singleton<T>::Singleton(Singleton<T> const &other)
    {
        *this = other;
    }

    //Destruction

    template <typename T>
    Singleton<T>::~Singleton(void)
    {

    }

    //Surcharges

    template <typename T>
    Singleton<T> &Singleton<T>::operator=(Singleton<T> const &other)
    {
        if (&other != this)
        {
            m_pInstance = other.m_pInstance;
            m_Instance = other.m_Instance;
        }
        return (*this);
    }

    //Others

    template <typename T>
    T *Singleton<T>::GetSingletonPtr(void)
    {
        if (m_pInstance == NULL)
            m_pInstance = new T();
        return (m_pInstance);
    }

    template <typename T>
    T &Singleton<T>::GetSingleton(void)
    {
        return (m_Instance);
    }

    template <typename T>
    void Singleton<T>::DestroySingleton(void)
    {
        if (m_pInstance != NULL)
        {
            delete (m_pInstance);
            m_pInstance = NULL;
        }
    }
}
```

Then, I've written the following code with the log 'constructor:toto' in the constructor of the singleton class 'TestSingleton'.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Singleton.hpp>

class TestSingleton : public core::Singleton<TestSingleton>
{
        friend class core::Singleton<TestSingleton>;
    private:
        TestSingleton(void)
        {
            std::cout << "constructor:toto" << std::endl;
        }
};

class HandleSingleton
{
    public:
        void Handle()
        {
            TestSingleton &test = TestSingleton::GetSingleton();
        }
};

int main(void)
{
    getchar();
    return (0);
}
```

The output is the following:

```
$> constructor:toto
```

I don't understand why a variable with reference is initialized even if the method that initialize this reference (here the method 'Handle') is not called ?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: template <typename T>
    Singleton<T> &Singleton<T>::operator=(..) Never do it. You must never define copy constructor and assignement operator for singleton. And good idea is to declare(not define) them private - in case of sudden usage of them you will get an easy catched compile-time error.

Comment: @FominArseniy: in C++11, you can also declare them deleted: `MyClass(MyClass const&) = delete;` which is even better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Singleton class uses a static instance of `T`. This instance will be initialized during program startup, before calling `main`.

The following code from your paste initializes the instance:

```
//Globals initialization

// […]

template <typename T>
T Singleton<T>::m_Instance = T();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your program invokes a static initialization of `T` instance and  C++ Standard n3337 **§**  3.6.2/2 says:

> Variables with static storage duration (3.7.1) or thread storage
> duration (3.7.2) shall be zero-initialized (8.5) before any other
> initialization takes place.
>
> (...)
>
> Static initialization shall be performed before any dynamic initialization
> takes place (...)

Answer (score 0):

Normaly we use the idiom "Construct On First Use" when implement a Singleton class.

The idiom correct some problems on the order of construction of the statics objects (you can search for the static initialization order fiasco).

Just put your static declaration on the getObject method. The constructor is then called after the first call of this method.

The constructor of a Singleton have to be private.

After that, a Singleton is by definition not copyable. You have to make private the copy constructor and operator=.